# Converting 1x4 grid to 2x2 when not enough vertical space

Tags: css

I have a 1x4 grid that looks like this.

[image]

The problem is that when the screen is widened, the buttons sometimes get cut off, and when they don't they're too horizontally stretched.

[image]

I would like to adjust the 1x4 grid to become a 2x2 when there's not enough vertical space.

[image]

I know this is possible with flex containers, but I'm failing in my attempts to figure out how.

This is my codepen:

https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/ZEKYwWJ

And this is the relevant code:

```
.multiple-choice {
}

.answer-1 {
    grid-rows: 1/2;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
    height: 98%;
}

.answer-2 {
    grid-rows: 2/3;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
    height: 98%;
}

.answer-3 {
    grid-rows: 3/4;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
    height: 99%;
}

.answer-4 {
    grid-rows: 4/5;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
    height: 99%;
}

.checkbox {
    grid-columns: 1/2;
    max-height: 90%;
    background-image: url('checkbox_unchecked.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.button-container {
    grid-columns: 2/3;
    height: %;
    padding-left: 5%;
}

.button-container button {
    width: 100%;
}

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: black; /*Button Color*/
    color: #f5f5f5;
    border-bottom: solid 4px #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: hack;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-size: clamp(1rem, 3vw, 2rem);
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.btn:active {
    /*on Click*/
    -ms-transform: translateY(4px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(4px);
    transform: translateY(4px); /*Move down*/
    border-color: black; /*disappears*/
}
```

Comment: That's what media queries are for.

Comment: The thing I don't understand though is how do I define a media query for when there's not enough vertical space for the buttons? I know how to do a media query for if the screen size is a certain size, or even if the orientation is horizontal. But sometimes the buttons cut off even if the screen is stretched horizontally just a little.

I thought the container would always stay within the vertical border because I'm defining height as a percentage?

Comment: not too sure what you're at, display:grid and auto-fill should do  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/YzVXxRv

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was trying to do but the main issue is that when resizing, there's still screen sizes where the button cuts off at the bottom before it changes to 2x2. Is that because of the values of clamp? I'm guessing there's no way to handle that in a dynamic way without specifying vw and vh values? For all of my code I tried to use percent values to avoid elements hanging off the edge of the screen, but the bottom of that button keeps getting cut off when I really need it to have a consistent margin. Is that an issue with my code or is there no way to avoid that?

Comment: I would drop the % and start from 100vh on your main container  and use grid or flex on each levels,  that way you wil not have to bother about % , fr(fraction)  will do for grid. Do the first level, then the sub ones. Not sure fixed is necessay. make . margin can be turned into a padding from the parent.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I actually rebuilt my entire CSS recently to avoid using 100vh, because of the bug/feature where using 100vh doesn't account for the navigation bar on mobile devices. There are some fixes for it using PostCSS I was never able to get working, so I went back to using %. Using fr for the grid is a great tip I wasn't aware of though, I appreciate that.